# Layout using Bootstrap and Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a company intranet page, with a "grid" style layout. In the past I've used tables, however I know that these are extremely problematic when used for layouts, hence I am attempting to construct the layout using bootstrap and Divs - however it's proving problematic.

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve in the top right hand corner of the page is:

[image]

However what I'm ACTUALLY rendering is the following:
[image]

Ignoring the fact that the weather data is a little more expanded, I'm struggling to get the desired result and am really tempted to revert back to tables to get this thing to line up!

Here is the code that I am using on the main template page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/companylogo.png" style="float: right; padding-right: 15px; padding-bottom:25px;"/>
        <div style="padding-top:25px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
            <div id="weatherDiv" style="float:left;"></div>
            <div id="dateDiv" style="float:right; padding-right:10px; vertical-align: bottom;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then upon page load, the two DIVs (weatherDiv & dateDiv) are filled in using AJAX:

WeatherDiv:

```
<div id="weatherDiv" style="float:left;">

<link href="/Content/css/weather-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/css/weather-icons-wind.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
    <ul style="list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; padding-left:0px;">
            <li>Brisbane - Hot and sunny - 32c <i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></i></li>
            <li>Melbourne - Early shower or two - 17c <i class="wi wi-showers"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>


</div>
```

DateDiv:

```
<div id="dateDiv" style="float:right; padding-right:10px; vertical-align: bottom;">

<h4>Friday, 20 November 2015</h4>
</div>
```

I understand totally that my use of CSS, Bootstrap & Divs are almost laughable, however the above is a result of hours of trying and trying!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you put it simply what the actual problem is?  I'm looking at both images, but I'm not entirely sure what's wrong.  Are you trying to line up the rows vertically or horizontally?  More description of the problem itself would be helpful.

Comment: You should try to avoid css floats as they are not really all that compatible with bootstrap (which should take care of where the element goes on the page for you)

Comment: Yep - apologies for not being clearer
1) Need the underline to go underneath the weather & date divs, however seems to be going behind the logo
2) Need to have the date vertically aligned to the bottom, I thought that vertical-align: bottom; would do this however there still seems to be a gap.
3) Am I using, for lack of a better term, "Best Practice"? I feel like lots of little "padding-left/right" isn't the most correct/best way to achieve what I need - but I really am clueless as to how to do it correctly?

Comment: I've updated my answer and fiddle to include HR

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be exactly sure how you want this layout to work on mobile. But here is a jsfiddle I've created that could help.
https://jsfiddle.net/2dqqajs1/

```css
body {
    min-width: 320px;    
}

.text-right img{
    display: inline-block;
}

/*extra small screens only*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #weatherDiv{
     text-align: right; 
    }
}

hr {
    margin: 0;
    border-top: solid 2px #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=CompanyLogo&w=400&h=100" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="dateDiv" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 text-right">
                    <h4>Friday</span>, 20 Nov<span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">ember</span> 2015</h4>
                </div>        
                <div id="weatherDiv" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5">
                    <ul style="list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; padding-left:0px;">
                        <li>Bris<span class="hidden-sm">bane</span> <span class="hidden-xs">- Hot and sunny </span>- 32c <i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i></li>
                        <li>Melb<span class="hidden-sm">ourne</span> <span class="hidden-xs">- Early shower or two </span>- 17c <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i></li>
                    </ul>        
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"><hr/></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>                    
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry original answer had a bad fiddle link, I've updated the link.

Comment: Awesome thanks for that - I've replaced it with our logo and it seems that it's left aligning the weather and logo:

[See Actual Example](http://www.advancenational.com.au/actual.png)

However what I need is the logo & weather to be right aligned:
[See Expected Example](http://www.advancenational.com.au/expected.png)

cheers

Comment: Updated fiddle and answer to right align logo and weather. But I really am just guessing what you want at the smallest screen size. Bootstrap is a mobile first framework, if you could show an example of what you want for Mobile, then Small, then Larger screens that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I am only designing this for Desktop PCs, so I guess the fact that I am using Bootstrap for this shows my lack of knowledge in this area. Is there a better library to use for this?

Comment: While Bootstrap is a responsive framework, it is also suitable to use in a non-Mobile environment you can force this if you need to by setting a min-width on the Body. I’ve built several responsive websites with Bootstrap but I’ve also implemented Bootstrap in internal Information Systems where the majority of users are Desktop PCs. I’ve found the CSS, JS and overall theme speeds up development, plus there is great community support should you need to ask for help.